# Is it possible to obtain the Instagram 'location-id' given the coordinates?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to obtain the Instagram location-id of a location, but I have only the coordinates of that location. Is it possible to get it automatically by using the API?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `location/search` endpoint to search the coordinate and it will show all the nearby locations.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat=LAT&lng=LNG&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/locations/#get_locations_search

Answer (score 0):

```
Request Url : https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?access_token=&lat=12.8282669&lng=80.0511868&distance=100&count=1

Getting improper response When I try above location search ,

Response: 
{
"data": [
{
"id": "112419772139227",
"name": "CEOA Matriculation School",
"latitude": 9.90604,
"longitude": 78.10873
}
],
"meta": {
"code": 200
}
}
```